# getting data from database table using cursor in android

Tags: android

I have one `employee table` which has column values

```
("store_loc_id","name","password","address_id","role_id",
"retailer_id").
```

I want to get the `name` and `password` from this table using cursor. how can i do??

Comment: Have you checked javadocs? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html #`query` method

Answer (score 1):

Haven't check this code, but the idiom should be understandable.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
if(cursor !=null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
     String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor getEmployee() {
    try {
        return db.query(employee, new String[] { "name", "password" },
                null, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("Exception on query", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}


Cursor c = db.getEmployee();
    if (c == null) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String Name = c.getString(0);
                    String Password = c.getString(1);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: I need the values of user name and password. Bu using db.getValues() i want to get the values. But what i have to write inside the getValues() that i am not getting.